# Множественный SQL Insert не работает, если одна из строк не попадает под условие уникального индекса

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, index

Есть уникальный индекс по нескольким столбцам(Name,Datetime). Я периодически делаю запрос к другому сервису и вношу данные в мою таблицу.  Я формирую множественный Insert запрос, и сперва все данные вносятся, а потом при обновлении с сервиса часть данных одинаковая и я вношу данные в таблицу, но так как уникальный индекс блокирует внесение, то весь запрос не срабатывает.
Я хочу вставить только те строки, которые новые. Те, которые не изменились- не вставлять.
Пример- мониторю количество продуктов:)) на сервисе

```
яблоки  29.10.2017 18:00:00 20(тонн)
груши   29.10.2017 18:00:10 60(тонн)
```

Через минуту

```
яблоки  29.10.2017 18:01:00 1000(тонн)  //ИЗМЕНИЛОСЬ
груши   29.10.2017 18:00:10 60(тонн)    //не ИЗМЕНИЛОСЬ- тоже отправлять на вставку,но эта строка не отработает из за уникального индекса
```

потом опять обновляю и надо вставить только те, которых не было.

Comment: Какую СУБД используете?

Comment: @"Sergey Gornostaev"  postgresql  Добавил метку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте предложение `ON CONFLICT`, вот как в примере.

```
INSERT INTO
  fruits (name, some_datatime_field, weight)
VALUES
  ('яблоки', '29.10.2017 18:01:00', 1000),
  ('груши', '29.10.2017 18:00:10', 60)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```